# Dynamic .load filepath, based from SVG path click

Tags: jquery, svg

So I've created a Map using SVG points, and raphael.js.

can check it out here http://laithazzam.com/work/helpmeplz/

I'm trying to load in new content to the page, based on which land mass is clicked.

What would be the most efficient method to dynamically accomplish this?  Each SVG path has a name and url defined within the path.js file, and ideal i'd like the click to pull the id, and apply it to the .html,

**For example**

Clicking area 1, it loads content from area1.html into a specific div within this document.

**I do have a click function working

```
.click(function(){
        location.href = paths[arr[this.id]].url;

       $(".video-js").animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
            $( "#map" ).animate({
                opacity: 0
                }, 2000, function() {
         $( "#map" ).css({ 
            "top" : "-610px",
            "opacity" : "1" 
         });
         $( "#map_btn" ).animate({
             opacity: "1",
             zIndex: "25"
         });
      }); 

        $( "#map_close_btn" ).animate({
                opacity: "0",
                zIndex: "20"
                },500); 
            })
        }
    });
```

I feel like within here, I should be able to pull the id, and plug it into

```
$( "#content" ).load( "area1.html");
```

but how would I go about making that "area1.html" dynamically inputted based on the click?

Thanks a bunch in advanced, let me know if you need anything else from my side!

Comment: What you have been tried so far?

Comment: I was going for a "hashchange" solution, like the plugin shown here, http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

I've gotten the location to be attached to the URL, I guess what I need help with is creating the listener, that will load the content once that #area1 is added.

From that point, I've struggled with getting a dynamic file path fed into the .load() function, pulling the specific "area" name into the .html string